# Determine average noise in a shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, average, noise, luxembourg

I am completely new to QGIS.

I am currently undertaking an analysis on urban green spaces (UGSs) in the city of Luxembourg.

I have noise data (expressed in Lden (dB)) on car, rail and air traffic  which I imported as shapefiles into QGIS.

[image: Car, rail and air traffic noise]

I have then clipped the noise shapefiles so that only those portions of the noise shapefiles that overlap specific UGSs remain.

[image]

Consequently, each UGS appears subject to different Lden (db) levels (as illustrated by the various colours covering each UGS) as some parts of an UGS may be close to a busy street while another part might be closer to a railway line.

**For subsequent analysis, I need an average noise value for each UGS.
I was now wondering whether there was a way to determine such an average noise value (in Lden(db)) for each UGS in QGIS?**

I realize that the physical properties of sound mean that a simple arithmetic average doesn't work here.

Someone mentioned to me I might have to transform the shapefiles into point layers and make some kind of spatial joint yet I am unsure as to what that means or how it's done.